# Fastlane either hangs on Mac or gives an error on Windows, need to build an iOS app

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular, fastlane-match

With my team we have been trying to create an IPA file to test on an iPad. We are using NativeScript with Angular, the app has been fully developed in a Windows computer so we have tried using the CircleCI method that NativeScript is giving as an option.
Trying to build the IPA file has not gone great, we try running

```
fastlane match <-- On Mac

fastlane match import <-- On Windows
```

on a personal Mac computer then it hangs when cloning with the SSH link, and when we use the Windows company computer (it is behind a proxy) it gives the error of needing to manually clone, however when cloning manually it denies access even though we do have access. Is there anything we may be missing?
(Error on Windows)
[Windows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvbfk.png)